# is it better to use the Hresult of an error or checking in the database befor executing the process?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, try-catch

is it  better to use the Hresult of an error or checking in the database befor executing the process?

for example

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{

    company NewCompany = new company();
    TryUpdateModel(NewCompany);
    context.companies.Add(NewCompany);
    try
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if(e.HResult== -2146233087)
         TempData["message"] ="This email is already registered";
        return RedirectToAction("signIn", "Accounts");
    }
```

I do not know which one is better for performance to hit the database or to use the try-catch block so please could anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your cases. If half or more your requests ends with error "This email is already registered", then Exception checking is not the best choice. But if errors occures from time to time it's OK to use tru-catch blocks.

Comment: but my question is not about the type of the exception, it is about to hit the database or to use the try-catch block :)